# How would you trim this in Arcmap SQL?

Tags: python, sql, arcmap

Hoping an Arcmap person can steer me in the right direction. I haven't managed to find a specific answer for this online anywhere for Arcmap SQL or even Python.

I need just the R10 or the L3 in the 2 examples below to be what will then display for labelling on a map. How would you trim this?

2 examples of the text fields says:

```
LOC: R10, SIGHTED BESIDE PALM TREE
```

or

```
LOC: L3, SIGHTED BESIDE DRIVEWAY
```

Presently I'm trying to just get the first 5 things to disappear without luck. At the moment it looks like:

```sql
SELECT TRIM ('LOC: 'FROM'PHOTO_LINK')
```